# Change ImageView Drawable inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So, I've got a Fragment with a [ViewPager inside it](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/viewpager-without-fragments/). I want to change image of layout inside the ViewPager through the fragment.

To do this I've written the following code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab,container,false); //fragment layout
    imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_image, null, false); //layout that's used in viewPager
    theImage = (ImageView) imageLayout .findViewById(R.id.image); //getting the ImageView

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.resultImagesPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ResultImageAdapter(getActivity()));
    }
```

The code itself doesn't crash my app, but no matter what I write I can't change the Bitmap of ImageView

Comment: try: theImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);

Comment: That wouldn't work, since `R.id.image` is declared in `view_image.xml`, not `fragment_tab.xml`

Comment: but as Marlen written, you are not inflating ViewPager here. Where do you inflate it?

Comment: I inflate it in the Fragment - I added the lines to the code snippet.

Comment: Then change the image inside of adapter

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do - dynamically change the image inside of adapter...And that's what I fail to do.

Comment: Then it's nothing to do in fragment. Show your adapter code

Comment: The code I used for viewPager is linked in the question

Comment: just change the drawable inside instantiateItem() of the adapter, after inflation and before adding to the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change drawable inside of ViewPager adapter.
In This case your adapter can look like:

```
    private List<YourObject> mList;
    // pass list of items into constructor
    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, List<YourObject> list) {
        mContext = context;
        mList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        CustomPagerEnum customPagerEnum = CustomPagerEnum.values()[position];
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(customPagerEnum.getLayoutResId(), collection, false);
        // get corresponding object and retrieve needed drawable
        YourObject yourObject = mList.get(position);
        ImageView theImage = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
        theImage.setImageDrawable(yourObject.getYourDravwable());

        collection.addView(layout);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }
```

...

and in your Fragment:

```
List<YourObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
// add your objects or whatever
list.add(new YourObject(name, drawable);
viewPager.setAdapter(new ResultImageAdapter(getActivity(), list));
```

Answer (score 0):

in this line you just create new instance of R.layout.view_image, and this created view not added on any container

```
imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_image, null, false);
```

Comment: So, you're saying I'm writing the code in the wrong place? I mean, right now, my code supposedly works like this: ViewPager contains `view_image.xml` with default image -> Fragment.java accesses `view_image.xml` and changes image inside it -> ViewPager now has `view_image.xml` with changed image.

Comment: v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab,container,false); on this inflater you put container (second parameter)  and when inflater will create layout from xml it add this layout to the container , but imageLayout you created without any container and this layout just created on memory but not displayed on the screen